# link_to not working with extra parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use link_to to create a link that goes to the new/create page like so: "new/2011/5". However, when I use the code below it create a link that looks like "new.2011?=5".

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_money_path(params[:year], params[:month]) %>
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact the default new action ror creates doesn't take any extra params. Is there a way around this?

My routes page includes the line:

```
match "money/new/:year/:month" => "money#new"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to name your route for that helper to reference it.

```
match 'money/new/:year/:month' => 'money#new', :as => 'new_money'
```

And then your `link_to` should work. A quick note though: your link text says "Edit", but you're creating a new resource. This might not be a good UI decision. Also, you probably want to constrain your route to `GET` requests like `get 'path/:to/:whatever'` instead of `match`.

Also, you appear to have a call to `resources` somewhere in your routes for this already. Since you probably don't want two routes to the same action with different parameters in this case, you should skip the `new` method so your routes look like this:

```
resources :monies, :except => [:new]
get 'money/new/:year/:month' => 'money#new', :as => 'new_money'
```

Comment: This works great. The "Edit" text was a mistake while copy/pasting it over, but I'll change my original point for future reference. I'll look into using GET over match. Again, thanks.

Comment: @jmspikers Updated with a bit more info and an example with `get`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use button with POST, instead of link / GET for creating new item.

Comment: The `new` action expects a GET HTTP verb. Perhaps you're thinking of `create`?